# creating iphone app for existing site. need advice about the data I'm downloading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, image

I'm building an iPhone app for existing site (a local news site)

Main page with articles headers, when click on them you move to the article page. Simple.

This is the first time I'm building such type of app.

I have 3 general questions, just to make sure :

1. For the iphone, Do we need to
   re-create the website article's
   pictures for the iphone ?   or there
   is some programming tool that on the
   fly make the files looks better on
   the iphone ? or maybe, there is some
   technique that creates one artice
   picture that looks right both for
   the server and the iphone ?
2. Usually, Do you need to create
   special data channels from the
   iPhone webservice ?   or programmers
   just use the existing rss channels
   of the webserver ?
3. If someone know nice artice about
   this stuff, It will help a lot. just
   see what other are doing.

thanks.

Comment: You can make use of the existing RSS feeds provided by the web server. NSXMLParser can be used for parsing the XML file.

Comment: Would be nice if you accepted an answer or upvoted.

Comment: @changelog - If it's a first question you can't really judge them by their acceptance ratio. Would be nice if you were more welcoming.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the intent Media apps, these apps are working like what you want your app to.

Answer (score 0):

1) You're better off creating mobile versions of the images. You can do image processing on the iPhone, but you'll have to have the original and that makes the whole thing pointless (ie. you have to download the whole thing.) Generate a mobile thumbnail when those are uploaded on the server.

2) RSS will do. There's a very good tutorial [at cocoadevblog.com](http://cocoadevblog.com/iphone-tutorial-creating-a-rss-feed-reader) about approaching such a task (I guess this covers 75% of the work you have to do)

3) Check 2) ;-)

Comment: thanks. more info about section 1 will help. what other are doing so the image will looks good on the website and on the iphone.

Comment: Basically, for number one, you'll have to change your CMS into generating thumbnails for iPhone. This can be quite simple with CMSs like Wordpress, Drupal. Can't help you more without knowing what you're running.

Answer (score 0):

if your download image is bigger the the thumbnail you are trying to display,
then the problem is in your code that change the image size. check carefully what are you doing to the image after downloading it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to create square thumbnails of your pictures at the server level. This will allow you to easily position in the iPhone screen, plus you will not need to download the whole image from the server.

nnahum